# Get content of HTML Headers

Tags: c#, web, voice-recognition

I am trying to make the Voice Recognition software on Windows 7 go to http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/ and fetch me a definition if any exist on any word I may give the recognizer.

My approach right now is fairly basic and most likely due to my inexperience with voice recognition. I took the example code from Microsoft's page and tried to modify the sre_SpeechRecognized() method.

I am stuck though, as I have no idea how to actually read the content of their HTML and show it in a RichTextBox. By reading the elements with Google Chrome I got the following information (this example is on the definition of Hair):

```
<div id="entryPageContent">
    <div>
        <section class="senseGroup">
            <h3 class="partOfSpeech">
                <span class="partOFSpeech">noun</span> <-- So it can be a noun
            </h3>
            <ul class="sense-entry">
                <li class="sense sense-type-core scrollerBlock">
                    <div class="senseInnerWrapper">
                    <a name="hair__2"> </a>
                    <span class="iteration">1</span> <-- First definition
                    <span class="definition">
                    "any of the fine thread-like strands growing from the skin of humans, mammals, and some other animals:" <--- The definition itself
                    </span>
                    <span class="exampleGroup exGrBreak">
                        <em class="example">coarse outer hairs overlie the thick underfur</em> <--- An Example
```

And the code goes on from there. A word can have more than one class (like Noun, Adjective, Verb, etc), a word can have more than one definition and a word can have more than one example because of multiple definitions.

The code that I have looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VoiceBotForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create new SpeechRecogniitionEngine instance.
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

            // Create a simple grammar that recognizes words.
            Choices words = new Choices();
            words.Add(new string[] {"define"});

            // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(words);

            // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(g);

            // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
                new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
        }

        void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Result.Text.Contains("define"))
            {
                String result = e.Result.Text.Replace("define", "");
                result.Trim();
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/" + result + "?q=" + result);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                //What do I do now??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code comment I am stuck at that point because I have no idea how to continue this after I get the initial response. When I got all the data I wanted to put it in a RichTextBox.

Comment: have u tried HtmlAgilityPack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/?

Comment: @AppDeveloper I have not, no.

Comment: do try it, it can make parsing thing easier

Comment: @AppDeveloper Thanks Buddy. Excellent feature. I am gonna start it now.

Comment: @AppDeveloper So..where do I start? The project got no documentation whatsoever ._. Now I just got a new problem Lol